# Why does index-of()  return multiple values when applied to a sequence of unique nodes?

Tags: xslt-2.0, saxon, sequences, indexof, xpath-2.0

I'm using xpath2's index-of value to return the index of current() within a sorted sequence of nodes. Using SAXON, the sorted sequence of nodes are unique, yet index-of returns a sequence of two values.

This does not happen all the time, just very occasionally, but not for any reason I can find. Can someone please explain what is going on?

I have worked up a minimal example based on an example of data that routines gives this odd behavior.

The source data is:

```
<data>
<student userID="1" userName="user1"/>
<session startedOn="01/16/2012 15:01:18">
</session>
<session startedOn="11/16/2011 13:31:33">
</session>
</data>
```

My xsl document puts the session nodes into a sorted sequence $orderd at the very top of the root template:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:variable name="nodes" as="node()*" select="/data/session"></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="orderd" as="node()*">
<xsl:for-each select="$nodes">
<xsl:sort select="xs:dateTime(xs:dateTime(concat(substring(normalize-space(@startedOn),7,4),'-',substring(normalize-space(@startedOn),1,2),'-',substring(normalize-space(@startedOn),4,2),'T',substring(normalize-space(@startedOn),12,8)))
)" order="ascending"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

Since the nodes were already ordered by @startOn but in the opposite order, the sequence $orderd should be the same as document-ordered sequence $nodes, except in reverse order.

When I create output using a for-each statement, I find that somehow the two nodes are seen as identical when tested using index-of.

The code below is used to output data (and comes immediately after the chunk above):

```
<output>
<xsl:for-each select="$nodes">
<xsl:sort select="position()" order="descending"></xsl:sort>
<xsl:variable name="index" select="index-of($orderd,current())" as="xs:integer*"></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"></xsl:variable>        
<session reverse-documentOrder="{$pos}"  sortedOrder="{$index}"/>
</xsl:for-each>
</output>
```

As the output (shown below) indicates, the index-of function is returning the sequence (1,2), meaning that it sees both nodes as identical. I have checked the expression used to sort the values, and it produces distinct and well-formed date-Time strings.

```
<output>
<session reverse=documentOrder="1"
        sortedOrder="1 2"/>
<session reverse-documentOrder="2"
        sortedOrder="1 2"/>
</output>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-index-of of `index-of` says "The items in the sequence $seqParam are compared with $srchParam under the rules for the eq operator. Values of type xs:untypedAtomic are compared as if they were of type xs:string.". So you are trying to compare untyped element nodes and that means they are compared as strings and both `session` elements have the same white space only string contents. That way both are compared as equal.

I am not sure what to suggest as I am not sure what you want to achieve but I hope the above explains the result you get.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will use index-of( for $n in $orderd return generate-id($n), generate-id(current()) ) instead. (Gerritt Imsieke suggested that on Saxon's help list.)

Comment: @DavidR: You don't really need to use `generate-id()` and can write your very simple `index-of()` function, as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

**Not relying on the `generate-id()` function, which is XSLT function, but not XPath function, one can write a simple `index-of()` function that operates on node identity**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:my="my:my">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:variable name="vNum3" select="/*/*[3]"/>
    
    <xsl:variable name="vSeq" select="/*/*[1], /*/*[3], /*/*[3]"/>
    
 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:sequence select="my:index-of($vSeq, $vNum3)"/>
 </xsl:template>
 
 <xsl:function name="my:index-of" as="xs:integer*">
  <xsl:param name="pSeq" as="node()*"/>
  <xsl:param name="pNode" as="node()"/>
  
  <xsl:for-each select="$pSeq">
    <xsl:if test=". is $pNode">
      <xsl:sequence select="position()"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

**the wanted, correct result is returned**:

```
2 3
```

**Explanation**: Use of the `is` operator.

Comment: I apologize for the nasty SO bug that sometimes formatted code is not indented.